# How can I export matrix from user input to other class as a two-dimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

So I wrote a method to make a matrix from user input like this:

```
public class matrix1 {
    public static void getMatrix() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of matrix rows. ");
         
        int matrixRow;
        
        do {
            System.out.println("Please enter valid number.");
            matrixRow = scan.nextInt()  ;
            } while (matrixRow>4);
        
         
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of matrix columns.");
        int matrixCol;
        do {
            System.out.println("Please enter valid number.");
            matrixCol = scan.nextInt()  ;
            } while (matrixCol>4);
               
        //defining 2D array to hold matrix data
        int[][] matrix1 = new int[matrixRow][matrixCol];
        
        enterMatrixData(scan, matrix1, matrixRow, matrixCol);
        
        // Print Matrix Data
        printMatrix(matrix1, matrixRow, matrixCol);
  }
  public static void enterMatrixData(Scanner scan, int[][] matrix, int matrixRow, int matrixCol){
     System.out.println("Please enter data for your matrix.");
          
          for (int i = 0; i < matrixRow; i++)
          {
              for (int j = 0; j < matrixCol; j++)
              {
                  matrix[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
              }
          }
  }
  
  public static void printMatrix(int[][] matrix, int matrixRow, int matrixCol){
    System.out.println("Your matrix is : ");
        
        for (int i = 0; i < matrixRow; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrixCol; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j]+"\t");
            }
             
            System.out.println();
        }
  }
```

And it works like a charm, but I'm a total beginner and now I want to use this created array to multiply it by a scalar. In my main method I invoke

```
matrix1.getMatrix();
```

The multiplying method is in another class. Can I import this user-made array and use it in multiplying class?

Answer (score 1):

Just change the return type to `int[][]` and add a return statement in the last line:

```
public int[][] getMatrix() {
   // ... you already got all this
   return matrix1;
}
```

Your main can then just call that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] matrix = getMatrix();
    // now you can just pass it to your multiplier as a parameter, e.g.:
    MatrixMultiplier.multiplyWithScalar(matrix, 2);
}
```

I would rename your `getMatrix` to something like `readMatrix` though, because there is a convention that methods named `get[SomeFieldName]` should be simple accessor functions that usually don't do a lot of work.

---

Better design, however, would be to wrap your primitive array as a member of your matrix class:

```
class Matrix {
    private final int[][] data;
    
    private Matrix(int[][] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    
    public static Matrix fromUserInput() {
        int[][] matrix1;
        // code for reading from input here
        return new Matrix(matrix1);
    }
}
```

and make your Multiplier accept an instance of your Matrix class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Matrix matrix = Matrix.fromUserInput();     
    MatrixMultiplier.multiplyWithScalar(matrix, 2);
}
```

Of course, now your matrix class needs to provide methods for getting and setting field values at specific indices.